# Define a title page using beamercolor environment

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to create a title page where it splits into 20% and 80% vertically and each has a separate color.
The logo should appear in the first column and located at the bottom whereas the title should appear in the second column and should be centered. But I can't get to this output. My working is as follows:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}

\titlegraphic{%
    \includegraphics[width=4cm,keepaspectratio]{logo}
}

\setbeamercolor{mycolor1}{fg=Black,bg=Green}
\setbeamercolor{mycolor2}{fg=Black,bg=Yellow}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=\paperheight,center]{mycolor1}%
    \inserttitlegraphic
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.80\paperwidth,ht=\paperheight,center]{mycolor2}%
    \insertauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It has some white space and the logo/text is not aligned properly.

Comment: Regarding the centered title: does centered refer to vertically ce ter red or to horizontally centered?

Comment: @leandriis The title should be both vertically and horizontally centered with respect to that particular column.

Comment: In your question you mention wanting to split the frame with a 20:80 ratio, while your MWE uses a 40:60 ratio. Is this intentional?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 20:80. I was experimenting with a few values. I will correct the post.

Answer (score 1):

- you can vertically centre the text by diving the total page height into a height and depth of the beamerolorbox
- to position the image at the bottom, you can use `\raisebox{-.5\paperheight}`
- the left margin can be cancelled with `\hspace*{-1cm}`

---

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}

\titlegraphic{%
    \includegraphics[width=.20\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
}

\setbeamercolor{mycolor1}{fg=Black,bg=Green}
\setbeamercolor{mycolor2}{fg=Black,bg=Yellow}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\hbox{%
\hspace{-1cm}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.20\paperwidth,ht=.5\paperheight,dp=.5\paperwidth,center]{mycolor1}%
    \raisebox{-.5\paperheight}{\inserttitlegraphic}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.80\paperwidth,ht=.5\paperheight,dp=.5\paperwidth,center]{mycolor2}%
    \insertauthor
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}}
\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]